# Is there any bundle analyzer for vite?

Tags: vite

We developed an app in vite and I want to analyze the bundle of app, I found rollup-plugin-analyzer but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `rollup-plugin-visualizer`;

```js
import { visualizer } from "rollup-plugin-visualizer";
...
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    visualizer({
      template: "treemap", // or sunburst
      open: true,
      gzipSize: true,
      brotliSize: true,
      filename: "analyse.html", // will be saved in project's root
    }) as PluginOption,
    ...
  ],
  ...
});
```

Comment: + `[yarn|npm run] build` to generate the output

Answer (score 63):

Alternatively, you can use [`vite-bundle-visualizer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-bundle-visualizer), which uses `rollup-plugin-visualizer`:

```bash
npx vite-bundle-visualizer
```

---

### Usage

```
# In your vite project's root
$ npx vite-bundle-visualizer
# Then open stats.html in browser
```

```
$ npx vite-bundle-visualizer --help

vite-bundle-visualizer

Usage:
  $ vite-bundle-visualizer <command> [options]

Options:
  --template -t <template>  Template to use, options are "raw-data" (JSON), "treemap", "list" (YAML), "sunburst" and "network" (default: treemap)
  --output -o <filepath>    Output file path, should be "**/*.html" or "**/*.json" (default: /Users/kuss/project/sides/oss/vite-bundle-visualizer/stats.html)
  --open <open>             Should open browser after generated, except when template is "json" (default: true)
  -h, --help                Display this message
```

### Screenshots

#### Visualizer Templates

##### Treemap

```
$ npx vite-bundle-visualizer
```

[image: treemap]

##### Sunburst

```
$ npx vite-bundle-visualizer -t sunburst
```

[image: sunburst]

##### Network

```
$ npx vite-bundle-visualizer -t network
```

[image: network]

##### Raw data

Output raw data (JSON) of stats

```
# @deprecated vite-bundle-visualizer -t json
$ npx vite-bundle-visualizer -t raw-data
```

[demo/stats.json](https://github.com/KusStar/vite-bundle-visualizer/blob/1983513/demo/stats.json)

Answer (score 0):

[vite-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-bundle-visualizer#vite-bundle-visualizer) works out of the box for vite

```bash
# In your vite project's root
$ npx vite-bundle-visualizer
# Then open stats.html in browser

# Use specified vite config file
$ npx vite-bundle-visualizer -c your.config.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to depend on [rollup-plugin-visualizer](https://github.com/btd/rollup-plugin-visualizer) or its wrapper like [vite-bundle-visualizer](https://github.com/KusStar/vite-bundle-visualizer), also try [vite-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/nonzzz/vite-bundle-analyzer) which graph looks similar with [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) since also using [@carrotsearch/foamtree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@carrotsearch/foamtree).